# How can I convert an audio file to a base64 string on ios with Phonegap?

Tags: javascript

My application at this point is very simple. It records an audio file. I want to convert the audio file to a base64 string using [readAsDataURL()](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/0.9.3/phonegap_file_file.md.html)
in the phonegap api. Here is my code below. As you can see, I am following the [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/0.9.3/phonegap_file_file.md.html) for getting the base64 string below. In the code below, I'm trying to get the base64 string and store it inside of a variable and then use that variable to display the string in a alert box for the moment. As of now, I only get "data:audio/wav;base64," I have been stuck on this for 4 weeks now. I would really appreciate some help.

```
 function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("myaudio.wav", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
 }

 function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);

 }

 function gotFile(file){
    readDataUrl(file);

 }

function readDataUrl(file) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    console.log("read success");
    console.log(evt.target.result);
    var thed = evt.target.result;
    alert(thed); //trying to display the base64 string in an alert box          
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);
    function init() {


      //This alias is a read-only pointer to the app itself
      window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "www/button-1.mp3", gotFile, fail);

      // var src = "/android_asset/www/sounds/button-1.mp3";

    }

    function fail(e) {
      // console.log("FileSystem Error");
      // console.dir(e);
    }

    function gotFile(fileEntry) {

      fileEntry.file(function(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function(e) {
          console.log("Text is: "+this.result);

        };

        // reader.readAsText(file);
        // reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        // reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      });
```